# Convert string to real date time value?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates, regex

Here is my current input:

```
14.05.20
12.37.01
```

And yes, as it shows, **there is** a line break in the cell...

Here is example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14nLk3nVaeknb9T1JS1EIdH5bqkENuj4OgxF0mPCrzmU/edit#gid=0

How could this be turned into an actual date and time?
I would love it if it could handle the whole column down

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit

In your [Google thread](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/50232532?hl=en#) you mention:

> *Would really like to be able to convert this in one formula/step.
>
> ...
>
> I would love if it if could handle the whole column down.*

In this case, you can use the following formula

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(  
     (REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"(^\d+\.\d+\.\d+)"),"\.","\/") 
     &" "
     &REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)$"),"\.",":"))
                          *1))
```

[image: Convert stings in a column to Date time, using an arrayformula]

---

Original answer:

The raw, unformatted value will be returned.
Format the result as `Date time` from the `Format` menu.

[image: Convert string to real date time value]

Functions used:

- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)
- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)

Comment: Hi! I tried messing with REGEX functions to no avail before. Your formula produced the following error for me: "Function MULTIPLY parameter 1 expects number values. But '//////// ::::::::' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number." You can see this on the example sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14nLk3nVaeknb9T1JS1EIdH5bqkENuj4OgxF0mPCrzmU/edit#gid=358943018

Comment: The formula did NOT copy correctly. Please check your sheet again. Formula is fixed.

Comment: The problem comes down to a displaying bug. Please see the correctly displayed formula on the image. Since you want an array as well, I also updated the formula to include an array.

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Thanks Marikamitsos - I am using this successfully and I find it easier to understand than alternatives. =)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to accept. Glad I could help :)